# Como pegar o nome da função atual?

Tags: php

Boa noite. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de pegar o nome da função que está sendo utilizada, tipo isso:

```
public function nome_funcao(){ 

    $nome_funcao = $this -> "nome_funcao";

}
```

Não sei se fui claro, mas quero resgatar o nome da função dentro da função que estou utilizando. Será que é possível?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `__FUNCTION__`

A partir da versão 4.3.0 do PHP existe a [constante mágica](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FUNCTION__` que faz exatamente esta função:

```
class Foo {
    public function method()
    {
        echo __FUNCTION__ ;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->method();
```

O código acima retorna `method`. Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HBu0/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/lpwRuM).

#### `__METHOD__`

Ainda existe a constante `__METHOD__`, a partir da versão 5.0.0 do PHP, que pode ser utilizada junto a classes e a diferença dela para `__FUNCTION__` é que `__METHOD__` retorna o nome da classe também.

```
class Foo {
    public function method()
    {
        echo __METHOD__ ;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->method();
```

A saída será:

```
Foo::method
```

Incluindo o nome da classe `Foo`.

É interessante salientar que quando o método executado for herdado de uma classe pai, o nome da classe retornado por `__METHOD__` será, também, da classe pai, pois é onde está definido o método.

```
class Bar
{
  public function method()
  {
    echo __METHOD__;
  }
}

class Foo extends Bar {}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->method();
```

A saída será `Bar::method` mesmo que o objeto seja uma instância de `Foo`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Obrigado

Comment: Existe a constante `__METHOD__` tambémque deve funcionar se está usando classes. Se existe uma diferenca, não sei dizer.

Comment: Acabei de reparar isso no manual que vc postou. Vou fazer uns testes. Abraço.

Comment: A constante `__METHOD__` retorna o nome da classe junto, esta é a diferenca.

Comment: Interessante o exemplo final que você colocou. Parabéns e obrigado.

Comment: Olá Anderson. Não sei se caberia uma pergunta no SOpt sobre isso, pois acho que a resposta é apenas um sim ou não. Esse método `__METHOD__` do php seria o que é chamado de reflexão? por exemplo: `$var = __METHOD__;`? Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho também. Reflexão é apenas a técnica de utilizar código para extrair informações do próprio código. Então, sim, é reflexão. Para outras situações, é possível utilizar a api [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.reflection.php) do PHP.

Comment: Interessante. Estava pesquisando sobre isso. Obrigado Anderson!